# Visual Studio Code Debug Nodejs Launch vs Attach

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

On Windows 8 I can debug a Nodejs app using `launch.json` without issue. However, on OSX I am forced to attach to a process instead. If I try to Launch a debugging session on OSX I get the error message:

> "cannot launch 'node' in debug mode."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In early versions of VSCode we've seen a timing issue on OS X that would result in the error message. Please upgrade to the latest VSCode (0.5.0) and try again.